# Pressure Washing with sodium hypochlorite (bleach) but I want to use coated sodium percarbonate

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

I am in the pressure washing industry. I don't want to use sodium hypochlorite (bleach) to clean exteriors of properties because it is so corrosive to my equipment and people's homes and businesses. I want to start using coated sodium percarbonate powder (peroxide). How much SP do I need to add to a gallon of water to equal 12.5% SH cleaning power. Also, it seems to only last about 6 hours. Is there another chemical I can add to it to make it last much longer?

Comment: Why don't you first dilute your bleach solution, before tying to change its composition ?

Comment: Define SH cleaning power, please? Bleach is indeed corrosive.

Comment: I'm afraid this might be a violation of Chemistry.SE's homework policy.

Comment: @AChem Coming from a non-chemist my definition of SH cleaning power is how much SP per gallon do I add to one gallon of water to equal the same cleaning power of 12.5% SH.

Comment: @John, You never defined what SH is ? After that you introduced a new abbreviation SP. Please write full words.

Comment: @AChem I believe OP is abbreviating sodium hypochlorite and sodium percarbonate but I agree with you to write full words.

Comment: I agree but he still does not define what cleaning power is. There is no measure of "cleaning"...hence there is no answer

Comment: While I applaud you're attempt to avoid more-toxic chlorine compounds, I don't know that there is a simple comparison of cleaning efficacy between hypochlorites and peroxides. Perhaps the manufacturers have a guide? Also, would not the *coating* on coated sodium percarbonate interfere with the pressure washer? See https://propowerwash.com/board/upload/threads/premade-sodium-percarbonate-siding-cleaning-mix.30867/